# Am I using maphighlight (jquery plugin) incorrectly?

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I'm trying to make an image map, but haven't been able to get it to work in both chrome and firefox, and I can't seem to get the maphighlight jquery plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight) to work correctly.  My example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SzpdQ/

Answer (score 2):

Your imagemap has `id="diagram-map"` whereas it should be `name="diagram-map"`.